# Free body diagram of two cards leaning against each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, torque, equilibrium

here is my body diagram:
[image]

he have the two weights two normals and two frictions however I think I am missing something becaused I only have cosine components when analysing the torque eq with respect to the left point:

$$\Sigma \tau = -0.5lcos\theta W_1-1.5lcos\theta W_2+2lcos\theta F_{f2}+2lcos\theta N_2$$
I think i am missing a force because I am asked to find the maximun angle without slipping

Comment: Hint:  What keeps the card on the left from falling down flat against the table?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert a normal froce exerted by the right card?

Comment: Right.  So try analyzing one of the cards on its own rather than both.  (A system consisting of both cards isn't really a rigid body anyhow, so treating it as such is suspect.)

Comment: You are missing the forces between the two cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to symmetry you can only consider one card, as if it is leaning against a wall

[image: fig1]

What you are missing is the force $A_x$ between the two cards.

Now you can take the balance of forces and torques

$$\begin{aligned}
 A_x - B_x &= 0 \\
 B_y - W &= 0 \\
 (\ell \sin \theta) B_y - (\tfrac{1}{2} \ell \sin \theta) W - (\ell \cos \theta) A_x & = 0 \end{aligned} $$

I have chosen to sum up the torques about the symmetry line, where it meets the floor as shown above.

As you can see the answer involves both $\sin$ and $\cos$ since forces exist in both horizontal and vertical directions.